# Does GestureRecognizers.Add adds the gesture to my grid every time I tap on the grid?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition

I have the following code in Xamarin Forms:

```
wordGrid.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
    Command = new Command(() =>
    {
       wordDetailGrid.IsVisible = true;
    })
});
```

I have over 10k words that I display randomly in the `wordGrid` by tapping the grid. Does this mean that if I displayed say 100 words by tapping the wordGrid it also adds the GestureRecognizer 100 times?

Comment: Each time you tap in the grid, a tap gesture recognizer´s event is launched and the coded associated to it is running...

Comment: I think it attaches only one recognizer to the whole place, that grid takes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it just adds the `GestureRecognizer` to your grid, not depending on what or how much elements are in your grid.

With your code, you can tap everywhere in your grid to execute the tap-command. That doesn't mean, that the underlying elements have this `TapGestureRecognizer`. This is working, because the parent view (in your case: the grid) has this recognizer.